# mysql how to concat/append binary data type

Tags: mysql, append, binary-data, stored-functions

I am trying to write a stored function which will return BINARY(20) type. I would like to format this return value, by putting string, itn, float values in it. But I couldn't figure it out how can I append binary data.

```
CREATE FUNCTION `test`() RETURNS binary(20)
BEGIN
declare v binary(20);

set v:= CAST('test' as binary);
set v := v || cast(5 as binary); -- I would like to append 5 as binary but how?

return v;
END
```

First line writes test as binary, at second line I would like to append 5 as binary. How can I do that? Thank you all..

Answer (score 2):

[`||` in mysql is logical OR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or) - you want to use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

`SET v := CONCAT(v, CAST(5 AS BINARY));`

instead of `CAST(5 AS BINARY)`, you can use the shorthand [`BINARY 5`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary).

Comment: I tried that but it converts 5 to char, I also tried number 659845 instead of 5, it uses 6bytes instead of 4 bytes, so it is not binary.

Comment: what do you want the `5` to be converted to? [`BINARY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-varbinary.html#binary-varbinary) means "byte *string*", so naturally an integer 5 is converted to the byte string '5'.

Comment: so did you make any progress in solving your problem? did you maybe figure out that packing different types into a BINARY string is not the best of ideas?

Comment: I confirmed this answer.  Here I convert two strings to binary data, concatenate them, and then convert the result back to a string:  `select concat(binary 'x', binary 'y') as binary_return_value, cast(concat(binary 'x', binary 'y') as char) char_return_value;`

Answer (score 0):

To concat 5, rather than character 5, use `char(5)` rather than `binary 5`.
So:

```
select concat("test", char(5))
```

returns a blob of 5 bytes. You can verify this with:

```
select length(concat("test", char(5))), hex(concat("test", char(5)));
```

To pad it out to a 20 byte array:

```
select convert(concat("test", char(5)), binary(20));
```

In your stored procedure, you just need:

```
set v:= concat("test", char(5));
```